# symfony 3 app fails silently to require_once in DebugClassLoader

Tags: php, symfony

I have a PHP class called `FilterInput`.  When my Symfony (3.0.3) based application calls a static member function of `FilterInput`, an implicit call to Symfony's `DebugClassLoader` is made.  The method is called `loadClass` and it starts like this:

```
public function loadClass($class)
{
    ErrorHandler::stackErrors();

    try {
        if ($this->isFinder) {
            if ($file = $this->classLoader[0]->findFile($class)) {
                require_once $file;
            }
        } else {
            call_user_func($this->classLoader, $class);
            $file = false;
        }
    } finally {
        ErrorHandler::unstackErrors();
    }
...
```

The issue I'm observing is that when execution reaches the `include_once` directive, the app fails silently.  That is, the http request returns empty and there is no output in `dev.log` or my apache logs.  I have verified that the `$file` variable contains the full and correct `/path/to/FilterInput.php`. I've also verified that this file is readable. So my questions are:

1. Why does execution stop at this point?
2. Why does it fail silently with no log error message or return data in the response.

EDIT: further information: if I fill in a junk path, e.g. "/foo/bar" then I do get an error message `Compile Error: AppBundle\Components\Factory::getDBO(): Failed opening required '/foo/bar' (include_path='.:')`; so presumably the silent failure is somehow related to the fact that there **is** a file at the given path.

Comment: Are you definitely in dev mode? In your app.php make sure you instantiate your AppKernel like this: `$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);`

Comment: that helped me find a lot of previously ignored errors - but I still get **silent** failures at require_once

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`require_once` will fail silently of couse if a directive such as:

```
defined('PATH_BASE') or die();
```

appears at the head of the source file; and the required definition does not exist